# Drupal 6 Advance Search Form with Views and CCK fields

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-modules

I am looking for Advance search module that'll expose CCK fields for search. I know using Views2 we can expose the CCK fields as a filter. However its not possible to convert CCK text fields as checkboxes. For e.g. I have added and exposed filter of group Search (Search: Search Terms). To assist I want to add 2 check-boxes like search in Title and/or Description which are CCK Text fields. I couldn't find way to change them as check-boxes with functionality search in Title and/or Description CCK fields.

Similarly, I want to add other assisting search fields like Search in Price Text filed with min-max (in- between)values, zip code + Geo-proximity search filters.

Could you please suggest me some module or hint to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters). It will allow you to use checkbox / radio elements

[Edit]

You may have to resort to using a hook_form_alter and hook_views_query_alter

In the form alter you can add elements to the filter form, and then in the views_query_alter you can change the query depending on the form values.

Comment: Hi Simon, Thanks for answer. But this couldn't work for me, as I have CCK fields of type text not the single or multi select type and the Better Exposed Filters module replaces the Views' default single- or multi-select boxes with radio buttons or checkboxes, respectively